# I need to delete multiple rows from multiple tables using foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, cascade

I have three different tables, `tbl1`, `tbl2`, and `tbl3` for example. I need to delete rows from each of the three tables.  Only problem is, there are foreign key constraints between each of the tables.  If I delete a row from `tbl1`, the delete cascades and deletes all rows from from `tbl2` and `tbl3` that referenced the deleted row in `tbl1`.  How can I delete only specific rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
 DELETE FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl3.tbl1_id = 'foo';
 DELETE FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.tbl1_id = 'foo';
 DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE tbl1.tbl1_id = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways

1. You should set foreign constraint **ON DELETE CASCADE** and delete it only from first table
2. You can do cascade manualy using 3 delete query

Answer (score -1):

if($_REQUEST['action']=='delete')
        {

```
        $id=$_REQUEST['site_id'];
        $qry_arry=mysql_query("Select site_name from site where site_id=$id and client_id='".$client_id."'");
        $site_qry=mysql_fetch_array($qry_arry);
        $site_nm=$site_qry['site_name'];
        $del_server=mysql_query("DELETE FROM `server` where site_name='".$site_nm."' and client_id='".$client_id."'");
        $del_work=mysql_query("DELETE FROM `workstation` where site_name='".$site_nm."' and client_id='".$client_id."'");
        $qry=mysql_query("DELETE FROM `site` where  site_id=$id and client_id='".$client_id."'");
        if(isset($del_server) && isset($del_work) && isset($qry))
        {
        $msg='<div style="width:450px; -webkit-border-radius:5px;   -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000000; text-decoration:none; border:solid 1px #999999; margin:5px; padding:5px; background:#BFFFBF;">Deleted successfully </div>';
                    echo "<script>window.location = 'https://portal.itimpulse.in/home-3' </script>";
            }       
                    exit(0);
    }
```